# when checkbox = true

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have been trying to work out my problem but I cant work out what to do.

[My JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/dLtecsbj/6/) has a dropmenu with a building level. Each building level has a value. I have a total value working, but I need to have a destroyed total. I have added a checkbox to use if its destroyed, but i cant work out how to do the subtotal. i did think of `ng-if` but cant work how to use it with what I need, but I welcome any help. I need subTotalOP to equal OP when checked is true, so I can add all the armour that is destroyed separately from the total

```js
var appBubble = angular.module('myExample', []);

function myCTRL($scope) {
  $scope.myOptionsOP = [{
    "armour": 1000,
    "label": "1"
  }, {
    "armour": 2000,
    "label": "2"
  }, {
    "armour": 4000,
    "label": "3"
  }, {
    "armour": 8000,
    "label": "4"
  }, {
    "armour": 16000,
    "label": "5"
  }, {
    "armour": 32000,
    "label": "6"
  }, {
    "armour": 64000,
    "label": "7"
  }, {
    "armour": 750000,
    "label": "8"
  }];

  $scope.myOptionsWH = [{
    "armour": 100,
    "label": "1"
  }, {
    "armour": 600,
    "label": "2"
  }, {
    "armour": 1100,
    "label": "3"
  }, {
    "armour": 1600,
    "label": "4"
  }, {
    "armour": 2100,
    "label": "5"
  }, {
    "armour": 2600,
    "label": "6"
  }, {
    "armour": 3100,
    "label": "7"
  }, {
    "armour": 3600,
    "label": "8"
  }, {
    "armour": 4100,
    "label": "9"
  }, {
    "armour": 4600,
    "label": "10"
  }, {
    "armour": 5100,
    "label": "11"
  }, {
    "armour": 9277,
    "label": "12"
  }, {
    "armour": 17280,
    "label": "13"
  }, {
    "armour": 415000,
    "label": "14"
  }];

  $scope.myOptionsLP = [{
    "armour": 450,
    "label": "1"
  }, {
    "armour": 788,
    "label": "2"
  }, {
    "armour": 1378,
    "label": "3"
  }, {
    "armour": 2412,
    "label": "4"
  }, {
    "armour": 4221,
    "label": "5"
  }];

  $scope.myOptionsSY = [{
    "armour": 2000,
    "label": "1"
  }, {
    "armour": 4000,
    "label": "2"
  }, {
    "armour": 6000,
    "label": "3"
  }];

  $scope.myOptionsDK = [{
    "armour": 550,
    "label": "1"
  }, {
    "armour": 1200,
    "label": "2"
  }, {
    "armour": 1850,
    "label": "3"
  }, {
    "armour": 2500,
    "label": "4"
  }, {
    "armour": 3150,
    "label": "5"
  }, {
    "armour": 3800,
    "label": "6"
  }, {
    "armour": 4450,
    "label": "7"
  }, {
    "armour": 5100,
    "label": "8"
  }, {
    "armour": 5750,
    "label": "9"
  }, {
    "armour": 6400,
    "label": "10"
  }, {
    "armour": 7050,
    "label": "11"
  }, {
    "armour": 9150,
    "label": "12"
  }];


};
```

```css
table,
th,
tr,
td,
p {
  font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<table border="1" ng-app="myExample" ng-controller="myCTRL">
  <tr>
    <td align=middle>Building</td>
    <td align=left>Level</td>
    <td align=middle>Armour</td>
    <td align=left>Destroyed</td>
    <tr>
      <td align=left width=100>Outpost:</td>
      <td>
        <select style="width: 40px" ng-model="OP" ng-options="value.armour as value.label for value in myOptionsOP"></select>
      </td>
      <td align=left width=200>Base Armour: {{OP}}</td>
      <td align=middle width=25>
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="subTotalOP">
      </td>
      <tr>
        <td align=left width=100>Warehouse:</td>
        <td>
          <select style="width: 40px" ng-model="WH1" ng-options="value.armour as value.label for value in myOptionsWH"></select>
        </td>
        <td align=left width=200>Base Armour: {{WH1}}</td>
        <td align=middle width=25>
          <input type="checkbox" ng-model="subTotalWH1">
        </td>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="4" align=left width=300>
            <br/>
            <br/><b>Total Of Destroyed Buildings: {{subTotalOP+subTotalWH1}}</b>
          </td>
          <tr>
            <td colspan="4" align=left width=300>
              <br/><b>Total of All Buildings: {{OP+WH1}}</b>
            </td>
</table>
```

Comment: What do you mean by _"I need to have a destroyed total"_ ?

Comment: Seems that the fiddle works fine

Comment: Total of armour destroyed is there. I need a subtotal of armour destroyed if the checkbox is true.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Updated:

I believe this is what you need:

```
{{(subTotalOP === true ? OP : 0)   + (subTotalWH1 === true ? WH1 : 0)}}
```

Actually, this is not the good approach, you should do the logic in the javascript. But anyway, hope this can sort your problem.

Checked new demo:
https://jsfiddle.net/dLtecsbj/10/

Comment: Oh yeah, I see now the error, seems that's the correct answer, but the question is difficult to understand. My upvote

Comment: I don't want a count of buildings destroyed, I want a sub total of the armour. As you can see, I have a total of armour, but i want a separate total of the ones that have been checked

Comment: I updated the solution, and finally understand what you want, please check if this is right for you :)

Comment: Thank you Joey, this is exactly the result i want. I assume then, there is a better way of doing what i want. Could you show me if there is. (if you are not busy that is)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ng-init` to initialize value to default value.

Issue is when you do `subTotalOP+subTotalWH1`, if `subTotalWH1` is `undefined`, it returns value of first operand(`true/false`). initializing it will also solve it, but you should initialize both.

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-init="subTotalOP=false" ng-model="subTotalOP">
```

[Updated JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dLtecsbj/8/)